# После загрузки на хостинг через background-image не отображаются картинки. WordPress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, hosting

Вот ссылка на сайт https://lolsmurf.pro/. Сайт на WordPress.

Вот так фоновая картинка не отображается.

```
<section class="promo_sect" style="background-image: url(https://lolsmurf.pro
/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/Viego_Splash.jpg)">
```

А вот так отображается

```
<section class="promo_sect" style="background-image: url(/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/Viego_Splash.jpg)">
```

Но если эту ссылку вставить в строку браузера
https://lolsmurf.pro/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/Viego_Splash.jpg  .
То картинка отобразится. Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: У Вас пробел или перенос на новую строку после https://lolsmurf.pro в пути к изображению после домена и перед слешем  `https://lolsmurf.pro /wp-content/uploads/2021/10/Viego_Splash.jpg`. Уберите и будет работать.

Comment: Спасибо!!! Убрал пробел через phpMyAdmin и заработало ))))